# XFCE un- lock screen not working (XFCE4, lightdm)

Tags: xubuntu, password, xfce, lightdm, lock-screen

In Xubuntu 18.x and Ubuntu XFCE 19.04, 19.10 (XFCE4, lightdm) I experience the un-lock screen does not show up. The screen remains locked!

Actually typing the password into the invisible lock sceen OPENS the lock!!!

That means the password request is working but does not show up. This is the reason why there are no error messages.

"light-locker-settings" explicitly tells me XFCE is controlling the "energy" settings. This works.

And there is no cover window over the GUI when it is "locked". The window in front of the main GUI does not show up (information not covered) and password entry does not show up.

QUESTION: How can I make the password request visible again??

Comment: Which release?   Xubuntu 18.04 has a different XFCE version, Xubuntu 19.04 is now EOL & thus off-topic (http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) whilst Xubuntu 19.10 uses GTK3 only and is thus different to prior releases.  Which are you using?

Comment: The problem is the same in all versions. I guess the composer or window manager has some issue not specific to the underlying tools. Current is Xubuntu 19.10 with lightdm. How can I see if the Energy / lock / windowmanager is based on GTK3? Wht difference it will make?

Comment: ..... RN: "Xfce Screensaver replaces Light Locker for screen locking."  Does this apply for upgrades??

Comment: Check, if you have `xfce4-screensaver` running in 19.10. If so, it should be used for locking automatically. If not, you could configure it to autostart in "Session and Startup" dialog.

Comment: And remember to disable autostarting 'light-locker' in the same dialog.

Comment: You don't need to reboot; just run `kill light-locker; xfce4-screensaver`

Comment: As for light-locker, there are bugs. Maybe these affect you? [Bug #1832960](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1832960), [Bug #1855753](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1855753)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @jarno. 

Light-Locker is NOT running, xfce4-screensaver is running; 

The two bugs do not apply at all. 

Based on the output of invoking "light-locker-settings" explicitly telling  XFCE is controlling I assume: This is not a light-locker issue. The config of xfce4-screensaver seems to work proper. The window handling is not.

Comment: Maybe [bug #1853709](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1853709)?

Comment: @jarno : YES, this is the same phenomenon, probably same bug. I "subscribed" via affects me, too.

Answer (score 3):

light-locker is buggy, see e.g.
[Bug #1832960](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1832960), [Bug #1855753](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1855753)

In 19.10 you can use `xfce4-screensaver` for locking, instead of `light-locker`.
In 18.04 (and in 19.10) you could use `xscreensaver` instead of `light-locker`. You have to install the screensaver first. Make sure only the one you use is autostarted during login in "Session and Startup" dialog.

You could use which locker you want with Xubuntu 19.10, see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Lock_the_screen) for instructions. As an administrator you could use any locker with an older release, too, by putting your version of `xflock4` script in /usr/local/bin. (Otherwise the default version at /usr/bin/ is used.)

Comment: sorry, this was the case all the time. the issue appears because xfce4-screensaver is the active process. light-locker is not in the process list. To have it bullet proof: can I de-install only "light-locker" without affecting other applications?

Comment: You may de-install light-locker if you do not use it. You could file a bug report about xfce4-screensaver using `ubuntu-bug xfce4-screensaver` and link it here.

Comment: `xfce4-screensaver` was provided for older releases (18.04) by the Xubuntu team members (via PPA; https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver); I recall the requests on IRC to test it, but that was long ago..

Comment: @guiverc you did not link any PPA, but you can find them in [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=xfce4-screensaver+bionic).

Comment: At the bottom of the page I did link was the *Xubuntu QA Staging PPA*, *Unit 193*'s & *Jonathon F's PPA*, all 3 of which contained the bionic code I would have tested on request (either Unit193 or Xubuntu QA)

Comment: I removed light-locker completely - no difference. This is a funny configuration issue. In other sitautions like time triggered locking the unlock screen appears. Closing the lid there is the problem. Now I get used to typing my password into the void and sesame opens the door. 

I did not  install a beta version. Not promising  since the normal version does work fine for most people. So it is not a general issue resolved by an upgrade of the software version. 

Recap: xfce4-screensaver actually uses the lock screen when closing the lid but does not show it. 100% reproducible.

Comment: @opinion_no9 I'm having the exact same problem. How did you solve it ?

Comment: @JonnyTischbein  Thanks for your interesting reply! I'm sorry, no. I did not solve the issue. I accepted to live with it and use my imagination instead.  For different reasons I had to do a new installation on the machine. For me the problem is buried not solved.

Comment: @opinion_no9 why not file a bug report, if you have a specific case when the screensaver does not work?

Comment: @opinion_no9 did the new installation affect to the problem?

Comment: @jarno  I'm sorry I mislead you: I exchanged the whole Linux system (now using U20.04 with XFCE4). Please pardon the lack of clarity.  A matching  bug report exists, as far as I remember. See  jarno Feb 17 at 11:52

Answer (score 1):

The availability of the XFCE lock screen(s) DEPENDS on the window manager!

- lightdm is NOT capable according to an error message first seen in U20.10.
- gdm3 IS capable to enable the lock screen.

So the issue is partly resolved: It DEPENDS on the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm having the same issue (see the comments at [answer #1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206043/429812), I did some research and found a solution.

It seems to be an bug of `xfce4-screensaver (0.1.8-1)` in ubuntu eaon.

Tomorrow on April 23th Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will be released. That providies `xfce4-screensaver (0.1.10-0ubuntu1)` which fixes the bug.

You can install the updated package now by downloading it from the via ubuntu package page: [here the .deb for amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/xfce4-screensaver/download)

Comment: I'm still having this problem on 20.04 and version `0.1.10-0ubuntu1`

Comment: @SkaveRat: 

yes, and Ubuntu 21 too ....  Try this: 

sudo dpkg-reconfigure   gdm3

and switch to gdm3 window manager. Does not hurt, is reversible and often solves the issue. Let me know!